# pdf StringIO embeded rendered html flask template

Tags: python, html, pdf, flask, reportlab

In my flask-app, i'm want to see a preview of pdf that will be generated, before definitely printing and saving it in my application_base_folder.
I could save previews on a tmp dir, but that's not what I really looking for.

I'm creating a pdf with report lab :

```
def gen_pdf(text):
    output = cStringIO.StringIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(output)
    c.drawString(100,100, text)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    pdf_output=output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    return pdf_output
```

The pdf would be then send to html template with my form to update part

```
class Form(wtforms.Form):
    text = TextField('text')

@app.route('/finalize/pdf/')
def finalize_pdf():
    form = Form(request.form)
    pdf_output = gen_pdf(form.text.data)
    return render_template('preview_pdf.html', form=form, pdf_output=pdf_output)
```

and in the html page, I have my form from which i can update the text, a button to POST value (it doesn't appear in the view finalize_pdf() ), and the pdf preview :

```
<form method='post' action={{ url_for('finalize_pdf') }}
{{ form.text }}
<input name='update' value='update'>
</form>
<br />
<embed src="{{ pdf_output }}" type="application/pdf" width='30%'>
```

The problem here is that "src" is probably looking for a path on the FS, I guess ? Anyway, it "dies" with this error :
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Am I so missing something, or is it impossible to embed / object in html a StringIO and I must write it on a tmp_path on my FS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit late but you could use base64 encoding for this problem:

```
from base64 import b64encode

# in your view:
return render_template(..., pdf_output=b64encode(pdf_output))
```

And your template:

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{ pdf_output }}" type="application/pdf" width='30%'>
```